# How do I set up custom bindings for DateTimes with breeze.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, knockout.js, breeze, momentjs

I'm trying to pull a DateTime object back from a database (using breeze), then trying to show a formatted date as a binding so that it can be edited and saved back to the DB. Problem is that somewhere along the line the Dates lose their "Entityness." I've tried using both custom bindings and computed observable examples from this site and others, to try to maintain all my Dates "Entityness," but nothing quite seems to work, either I can format the date OR save it.

Here's an example of a custom bind snippet I tried using:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.datetimevalue = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            // Use the value binding
            ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);

            // Provide a custom text value
            var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var dateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a";
            var strDate = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
            if (strDate) {
                var date = moment(strDate).format(dateFormat);
                $(element).val(date);
            }
            else {
                var date = moment(new Date()).format(dateFormat);
                $(element).val(date);
            }
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            // Use the value binding
            ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);

            // Provide a custom text value
            var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var dateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a";
            var strDate = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
            if (strDate) {
                var date = moment(strDate).format(dateFormat);
                $(element).val(date);
            }
        }
    };
```

In this example (taken from [this link](https://denverdeveloper.wordpress.com/tag/moment-js/)) the date is displayed in the specified format, but is not persisted back to the server. How can I display a formatted date using breeze/moment and then save any changes made to this formatted date?

Thanks in advance,

Lowz

Comment: I can warmly recommend the documentation at  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html (if you already haven't read it ;)

Comment: I wonder if you are maintaining the object properly - even if you overwrite the value the prototype of the Breeze object should still maintain the things that give it 'entityness', unless you are clearing the prototype as well.

Comment: I agree @pw-kad, after looking at the breeze documentation I came to the came conclusion, but due to my own inexperience with coding I haven't been able to find a solution from any of the official documentation provided (breeze/knockout websites). In the breezejs documentation it says: "Do not change part of a date and expect the entity to change its EntityState. It won't! Your change may not be saved." at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/date-time. Thing is I must be missing something glaringly obvious because no one else seems to be encountering this problem :(.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use knockout custom binding; Breeze and moment together can do the job for you by extending the orders table to whatever you wish for.

You would've put some useful details in your question.. but I assume the idea is the same. Nevertheless, I'll take the example of the orders table.

Let's say you want to display the order date to the client in the format `"DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a"`

```
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(remoteServiceName); // remoteServiceName is a string representing your controller path
 var Order = function() {
    this.formattedOrderDate = ko.computed(function () {
    var dt = this.orderDate();
    var value = (dt && moment.utc(dt).isValid()) ?
    moment.utc(dt).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a') : '[Unknown]';
    return value;
    });
    }
manager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Orders',Order);
```

This will show the date in the desired format.
For updating : set the orderDate() property to the computed value before calling `saveChanges()`:

```
order.setProperty("orderDate", new Date(order.formattedOrderDate()));
// Then....

manager.saveChanges();
```

This might be too late to answer your question, but I thought it might help